# Why does select_for_update never work for me in Django + Postgres?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I feel like I have some conceptual mis-understandings of 'select_for_update' in django.

Lets start with a few simple lines of code

```
Rank is a Django model.
Report is a Django model, with a bunch of Rank's.
```

Like so:

```
class Rank(models.Model):
    search_term = models.CharField()
    rank = models.IntegerField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField()

class Report(models.Model):
    ranks = models.ManyToManyField('Rank')
```

Simple enough.

I have a worker, his job is to check the last unique iteration of a 'rank' object based on the search term.  So if we have a search term 'foo', foo could have say 12 entries.  If the last entry is older than 24 hours, than we want to make a new entry to see what the new ranking is.

With me so far?

Okay.  So, here's where the problem happens.  Obviously, there are more than 1 worker.  So here is how I attempted to make sure to only write one record:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    # hidden code.. select the max (created_on) model of unique search_term

    # loop through the maxes
    for r in ranks:
        if q['max_date'] <= one_day_ago:
            ids_we_need_to_update.append(q['rank_id'])

    rows_to_update = Rank.objects.select_for_update(skip_locked=True).filter(pk__in=ids_we_need_to_update)[:16]

    for rtu in rows_to_update:
        #update row....
        rtu.save()
```

To my disappointment, I woke up this morning to see that a race condition had occurred, and the same search_term had been inserted into the Rank database twice, 2 seconds apart from each other.

What am I not getting?